# Amazon Redshift MOD calculation on numeric column causing error

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm getting this error when trying to do a MOD on a numeric column in Amazon Redshift database. Is this a bug or I'm I missing something?

```
create table sch.test123(abc numeric(10,5));
insert into sch.test123(abc) values(12345.345);
select mod(cast(abc as decimal(10,3)),cast('10.0' as  decimal(10,3))) from sch.test123;
```

Error is

> Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Comment: To start with: the `insert` should fail, since value `123456.345` cannot fit in `numeric(10, 5)`.

Comment: Made up an example and didn't notice that, edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in the `MOD()` function. It currently only works for INT and BIGINT data types. However you can use the [modulo operator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_OPERATOR_SYMBOLS.html) instead.

```
SELECT abc % 10.000 from #test123;
--  5.34500
```

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. We've identified the issue and are working on a fix. When fixed it will be noted in our maintenance announcements at the top of the forum. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=155&start=0

UPDATE: This issue is now resolved in the latest Redshift version.